# Mysql If question

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a chatbox IM.
I have a table where I want to update if the user closes the window, meaning he has viewed the messages his friend has sent him.
When this happens, each conversation has a unique id so I find messages with that id and set the viewed column equal to the users name.

However if the other user also closes the window I would like to change the viewed column to 'both' for all the messages so none of those messages pops up for either user. *(by default the viewed column is equal to 0)*.
What I want is a query that just finds all the messages with the `convo_id` and if that message is already viewed by another user meaning `viewed!=0` then it is set to both else it is set to the user closing the box.

I have a query but it doesn't work because I didn't quite get the syntax right.

**Just wondering if anyone could correct it or suggest something.**

```
$sql = "UPDATE chatbox IF (viewed!=?) THEN
        SET viewed=? WHERE convo_id=?
        ELSE 
        SET viewed=? WHERE convo_id=?";
$stmt18 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt18->execute(array(0,$receiver,$convo_id,'both',$convo_id));
```

Comment: Why not just generate two different UPDATE statements in your PHP code?

Comment: What flavor SQL are you using?

Comment: @AJ: Presumably because it would always take two SQL statements to execute.  One fo figure out which one to run, and one to run it.  Also that is a race condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll want to use a case statement:

```
update catbox
set viewed = case when viewed = ? THEN ? else ? end
where convo_id = ?
```

Comment: It works Paul, I really appreciate it, however what do you think about What George has to say about just creating a separate table?

Answer (score 1):

I propose that you create a second table (perhaps called 'views') to record this information. When the close event occurs, you insert a line into the table with the message id and the username.

This should simplify the query and avoid the creation of confusing data in the message table.

Comment: That is a good point, I always just thought adding another column was better than creating a wholllee table. I am somewhat paranoid about space haha.

Comment: If your new column will contain a unique piece of data, you are correct. However, since there is logic involved to determine what should be placed in the field, you are better off creating a separate table. This will also allow your application to scale -- what happens in your current scenario if you decide to support more than two users in each chat?

Comment: Thanks again George, good point again. I actually have other tables for other kinds of new messages and notifications. Maybe I can consolidate them.